# Найти ближайшую метку на Yandex Maps JS

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Ребят, такая проблема. У меня на сайте используется Yandex карты.

Я нахожу местоположение пользователя, но не могу дальше найти ближайшую точку на карте.
То есть у меня много пунктов на карте, я нашёл местоположение пользователя, далее мне надо предложить ему ближайший пункт.

Как это реализовать? В API Yandex я не нашёл ничего такого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для определения ближайшего к точке объекта в API Яндекс.Карт следует использовать [geoQuery](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geoQuery.html), а точнее его метод [getClosestTo](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult.html#method_detail__getClosestTo).